# Snapping points to lines in ArcGIS Desktop and automate using VBA?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vba, snapping

I use ArcGIS Desktop and I want create a network with a point feature and a line feature. I need my point features to be on the line features so I should do Snap point to line.

However, I do not know how do it in ArcGIS, and then automate it with code for this in VBA.

Comment: Did you try the Editor snapping environment?

Comment: "and then automate it with write code for this in VBA"

Comment: if points do not hold the critical information. you can also tr transform your line into points

Comment: You can refer this video to snap point features to a line feature using arcMap.. https://youtu.be/Lb-9ql_o4Sg

Answer (score 22):

## Snapping points to a line using ArcGIS geoprocessing tools

### Assumptions:

You have a point layer and a line layer.  You want a points to be snapped to the line layer.

### Instructions

#### 1. Use the `Near` tool to find snap locations

1. In ArcGIS's Toolbox pane, Select `Analysis Tools` -> `Proximity` -> `Near`
2. Choose your point layer as `Input features`, your line layer as `Near features`.  **Make sure you tick the `Location` checkbox.**
3. Four new attributes will be added to your point layer, `NEAR_FID`, `NEAR_DIST`, `NEAR_X` and `NEAR_Y`.

#### 2. Export the layer as a table

1. Open the attribute table of the point layer
2. Click on the `Table Options` button in the attribute table window, and choose `Export...`.  Save it is a dbase (`.dbf`) file.
3. When prompted if you want to add the table to your current map, choose `Yes`.

#### 3. Recreate the points layer from the table

1. Find the table you just added in your `Table of Contents` pane.  You might need to switch tabs if you are using ArcGIS 9.3 to the `Source` tab.
2. Right-click on the table, and choose `Add XY Data`.
3. Make sure the X field is set to `NEAR_X`, and the Y field to `NEAR_Y`.  Adjust the coordinate system if appropriate.
4. Your new point Event layer should appear in the table of contents.  Right click on it, and select `Data`->`Export data...` to save the layer permanently as a shapefile.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It is a clear method that I can immediately try.  I am able to work with the results to get what I need.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this solution works for users that have an ArcInfo (advanced) license.

Answer (score 6):

ArcGIS 9.3.x:

In the ArcGIS interface, use the [snapping environment](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_the_snapping_environment) within the Editing toolbar.

Programmatically, you can find a number of snapping-based Visual Basic examples at the [ESRI resources page](http://resources.esri.com) (note: personally, I like to use the old [page](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.3/NET/fa9c9ab8-05d4-4fbd-8e39-14ce1f7cab3f.htm). I think it's easier to find stuff. [VB resources](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/vb6_start.htm)). See for instance, [VB code to "bulk snap"](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/com_cpp/samples/com/Editing/edit_commands/bulk_snap/4eecfaa4-dce2-457c-b9e7-0881d5960436.htm): "The Bulk Snap command will take selected features and attempt to snap them based on the current settings of the Editor snap environment."

ArcGIS 10:

- [About snapping in ArcGIS 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000003t000000.htm)
- [VB Snapping in ArcGIS 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_batch_snap_selected_points/00010000003n000000/). (first
  code cample, others follow in the
  left Table of Content)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Hawths Analysis Tool. You can download it [here](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/download.php).

I found it [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/280162550/Hawths.Analysis.Tools.for.ArcGIS.9.3_www.elme-omran.com.rar) for ArcGis 9.3 but I warn you that I did not test it. If you have time you can try it.

Comment: I have it,but it can not work with ArcGIS 9.3.

Comment: I deleted your second answer and merged it into this one.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption** you have the Network Analysis Extension for ArcGIS (9.3) Sp3: Your 'Network'

Creating a Network >Arcatalog
(you must understand the TYPE of network you are trying to build first!)
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_a_network_dataset

You can automate this with ModelBuilder (Python)

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Add_Locations_(Network_Analyst)

{linear unit}
The search tolerance for locating the input features on the network. The parameter includes a value and units for the tolerance.

{source {snap type};source {snap type}...} point and line
**Allows you to specify which sources in your network dataset will be searched when finding locations**, as well as specifying what portions of geometry will be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools available on Arcscripts.  See this [search](http://arcscripts.esri.com/scripts.asp?pg=1&sb=1&ob=asc&eDate=&n=&top=&eLang=&eProd=&perPage=10&eQuery=snap+point+line&Submit2=search)

I cannot vouch for it, but [Snap and split program](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13206) looks like it fits your requirements?

Let me know if you have problems "installing" it or using it.