# How to connect stops to road for network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, snapping, multimodal-network, network-dataset

I have three files that cover a bus route network, road network and bus stops.

I want the bus stops to be the connections between the road network and the bus route.

When I try and build the network dataset I am getting a standalone user-defined junction error. I tried snapping the stops to the bus route and building a network dataset with just these 2 files but still got the same error.

I followed the instructions from here [Snapping points to lines in ArcGIS Desktop and automate using VBA?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/snap-point-to-line-in-arcgis) to do that.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? Optimal bus routes?

Answer (score 2):

First you should snap points to lines .You can use [GME](http://www.spatialecology.com/) (Snap Points to Feature ). If you want to use bus stations for routing you should create multimodal network.Follow the [Multimodal network excercise](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000005v000000). You should create stations,entrances, Bus lines , use ovverride for entrances then build your network dataset.

Answer (score 2):

The steps below require an Advanced license. Broadly, these are the steps:

1. Reproject layers to same projection
2. Use the "Near" tool to snap your stop points to your route lines
3. Export data table and create new points from "snapped" XY coordinates
4. Use the "Integrate" tool to make your snapped stop points and route lines coincident.
5. Use the "Split Line at Point" tool to split your route lines into segments.

In detail:

1. First, you'll need to make sure that your stops and routes are in the same projection. If not, choose a project to use for all layers, and reproject either (or both) by using `ArcToolbox --> Data Management Tools --> Projections and Transformations --> Project`.
2. Use `ArcToolbox --> Analysis Tools --> Proximity --> Near` to join your stops (Input Features) to your Routes (Near Features). Be sure to select the `Location (optional)` checkbox, which will create the XY coordinates for the "snapped" stops. This adds four columns to your stops data table, include NEAR_X and NEAR_Y with coordinates for the snapped points.
3. Export yours stops data table (the table, not the layer--Open Attribute Table, then from the attribute table choose "Export"), and click Yes when prompted to add the new table to the current map. Right click on your new table, and choose "Display XY Data" setting `X Field` to "NEAR_X" and `Y Field` to "NEAR_Y" and click OK. You should now see your stops projected immediately on top of your routes. Export the resulting layer to your file geodatabase (e.g. "Stops_Snapped") and add back to your map when prompted.
4. Next, you need to Integrate your Stops and Routes. Choose `ArcToolbox --> Data Management Tools --> Feature Class --> Integrate`. Add both your Routes and snapped stops (Stops_Snapped). (Be aware that Integrate modifies the underlying data--so make sure you're working on a copy!) Set a small but reasonable `XY tolerance` (e.g. 1 meter). (I'm not certain that this step is strictly necessary, but I included it my workflow and arrived at a successful output.)
5. Finally, split your Routes lines based on your Stops_Snapped points. Choose `ArcToolbox --> Data Management Tools --> Features --> Split Line at Point`. Set your Route as Input Features, Stops as Point Features. Specify your `XY Tolerance` (this may need to be larger than you would expect--e.g. 10 - 15 feet--experiment and see what works best).

Now, when you rebuild your network dataset with your new features, you should get an error-free build!

One final note: when you build your network dataset, you need to "connect" your streets to your public transit routes using the stop points you've created. (For more about connections, see [ESRI's help file](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/9a56b988-6f7c-464a-aa2e-ab6ed59455b9.htm).) You'll need to set you Connectivity Policy for your streets to "Any Vertex" and for your stops to "Override":[image: Connectivity Policy for joining public transit lines to street networks]

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to investigate the geometries involved. Note that snapping is not enough - the layers must be *coincident*, meaning in order for a network junction to occur there must be a vertex at the same point in all related layers. You can't just snap the stop points anywhere along a route segment/edge (nor for that matter will a junction occur just because a bus route line and a street line cross).

The second suggestion would be from the [help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Correcting_standalone_junctions/002r0000004s000000/) where there is a specific solution outlined for correcting standalone junctions (note it's in the geometric network section rather than the network analyst section):

> 1. Add the Geometric Network Editing toolbar to ArcMap.
> 2. In the ArcMap table of contents, select one of the feature classes that participates in the geometric network containing the illegal
>      features.
> 3. Click the Network Build Errors command to identify illegal features.
> 4. Locate the standalone junction to correct - These will have a build error code of 16.
> 5. Correct the junction in one of two ways:
>
>    - Delete the junction
>    - Connect the junction to the preferred edge feature

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and read this post http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/26566-Build-errors-in-Network-Dataset hope it will help you, just exclude the stops in the network, it worked for me.

Comment: While this post may be helpful for the asker to read, your Answer would be more valuable if you described the steps that you are proposing in some detail.

Comment: Also, since the asker specifically wants to use the stop locations as the connection points between the two modes, how would excluding them help solve the problem?