# Aligning point along the line in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have a line and some points along with line, but they are not equally distanced from line. I want to align them at equal distance along the line,
let's say, every point should be at a distance of 10 meter from the line.

[image: Problem Image]

I want to make an Python script for this, but don't know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/snapping-points-to-lines-in-arcgis-desktop-and-automate-using-vba?

Comment: Have you looked at Linear Referencing?

Comment: i was trying to understand liner referencing what i could understand that it creates a new dbase table. and may not be useful to actually realign the points itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a buffer along your line, then convert this buffer to polyline and finally use snap tool to snap points on this line. Python code should looks like this:

```
import arcpy

# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"path_to_your_workspace"

# Set variables
line_feature = "your_line_feautre.shp"
point_feaure = "your_point_feature.shp"
distance_from_line = "10 Meters" # distance for buffer

buffer_feaure = "in_memory" + "\\" + "buffer" # temporary feature
line_from_buffer = "in_memory" + "\\" + "line" # temporary feauture

# Make buffer along line
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(line_feature, buffer_feaure, distance_from_line)

# Convert buffer to polyline
arcpy.PolygonToLine_management(buffer_feaure, line_from_buffer)

# Snap points to line
distance_for_snap = "20 Meters" # distance for include points to snap
arcpy.Snap_edit(point_feaure, [[line_from_buffer, "EDGE", distance_for_snap]])

# Delete
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
```

You could see the help for tools: [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000), [Polygon to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003t000000) and [Snap tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000).