# Error: "No route from location 1 to 2"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, route, shortest-path

I want to find the shortest route connecting three points on a map.
I built up a road network, I snapped three points on the road.

I got this error:

**Warning: No route from location "Location 1" to location "Location 2".
Error: No solution found.**

[image]

I can find the road between point 1 and 3 (of the first map), but I got that error  for the road between 3 and 2 and 1 and 2. The road between 1 and 3 does not even look like it is the shortest path (see below).

[image]

Is it possible that can depend on some routes feature that does not me allow me to drive through those? so I can't reach the point 2 and I don't take 
the shortest roads.

The procedure I followed:

1) I snapped the points to the road as described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/1433/73176

2) I created the network from the road polyline similarly to this tutorial: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm

3) "Network Analyst" --> "New Route"

4) Right click on "Stops", "Add locations.." I added the three points

5) "Solve"

Comment: It seems likely to me that there are gaps in the network i.e. snapping errors - how confident are you with the data? Can you update the question with the exact tool and parameters you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time I've got the same problem, and I solved it by **planarization**.

Here is a documentation: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/planarize-polyline-features.htm

Just planarize your polyline layer and then you should get "clean" network without any intersections.

Comment: I don't know why but the planarization button stays unactivated and I can't proceed.

Comment: the projection of the road was different, so I converted it to my layers projections and the the planarization worked. It looks like it's working well now, better than before for sures, I will try also with other points to confirm it @dmh126

Answer (score 0):

Planarization fixed my issue. I created a fishnet over an area and running a network would not work. After I planarized my fishnet it worked.